# How to intercept requests from external handlers using Cypress?

Tags: request, cypress, intercept

Does anyone know how a request that launches an external handler (such as an email app) can be intercepted to obtain the `Request URL`?

The in-browser request that launches the external app looks like this:

```
Request URL:      mailto:example@example.com?Subject=Test&Body=test
Referrer Policy:  strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

I'm trying to do as follows and it doesn't work:

```
cy.intercept('mailto:**').as('mailto')

cy.get('#submitButton').click()

cy.wait('@mailto').its('request.url').should('contain.text', 'Subject')
```

It fails on `cy.wait('@mailto')` and the `Routes` from Cypress's interface presents the following (that it doesn't catch the request):

| Method | Route Matcher | Stubbed | Alias | # |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| * | mailto:** | No | mailto | - |

Also, already tried to use different Cypress versions: `6.4.0`, `6.9.1` and `8.2.0`.

Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @cody.tv.weber (since you created the bounty): When you access mailto URIs, does the element you're clicking always have an anchor element within it with the href set to a URI starting with "mailto:"? I don't know if it's even possible to use a mailto URI without '<a href="mailto:...">', but I would like to confirm that solving for the <a> case is the primary intent of the question and the bounty.

Comment: Yes, this is true.  So Graham Judd's answer provided below worked by just asserting on the href attribute and asserting the click.  The real issue is that the mailto causes special calls that are not true network calls from my understanding.  So there is no way to intercept them.

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct way to catch `mailto:` calls since they are not the correct protocol for `cy.intercept()`.

But you can test two aspects of the link

- does it contain the expected `mailto:something` address
- is it clickable

```js
cy.get('a')
  .should('have.attr', 'href', 'mailto:example@example.com?Subject=Test&Body=test')
  .then($a => {
    $a.attr('href', 'http://mailstub.com')  // modify to something intercept-able
  })

cy.intercept('http://mailstub.com', {})     // stub with empty object
  .as('mailto')

cy.get('a').click()
cy.wait('@mailto')     // fails if click does not occur
```

Comment: Seems like a good answer!  Ty!

Comment: We ended up just asserting the href.  But thanks for the extra click step, didn't think about that!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that mailto: doesn't seem to be a request, it's more like a link inside an `<a>` of your HTML...
A request usually has a method (GET, POST, DELETE) and a URL, and then you can intercept using `cy.intercept`.
It turns out that when you click on the link that contains Mailto a request is not created, this link serves to open your email client, so you need to create an assertion for this link in another way.

```
cy.intercept('POST', '/createuser*').as('createUser')
cy.wait('@createUser')
```

This is the way I use to intercept a request, making the test wait for the response before proceeding, it is for requests that your frontend makes to your backend server or third party services.